# File type for Windows Phone Tile

Tags: windows-phone-8, file-type

What Type of Image File should the Tile on a Windows 8 phone app be?

Does this file type allows Dynamic scaling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you are looking for

[Tiles wp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/design/jj662929%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

And here's a video link

[how to change size](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fUMZ2d_orPk)

and here's an interesting documentation on flip of tiles

[flip tiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206971%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)